# Android - how to force child to override parent method that has code

Tags: java, android, inheritance, methods

Here's the scenario -> imagine there are 3 classes, i want to do something kind of like:

```
public class GameObject {
    public void updateBounds() {
        // do something
    }
}

public abstract class Enemy extends GameObject {
    public abstract void updatePosition(){ //<-- this will not compile, 
                                    //but this is what i want to do, to force 
                                    //child to override parent method
        updateBounds();
    }

}

public class Minion extends Enemy {
    @Override
    public void updatePosition() {
        super.updatePosition(); // <-- how do i throw an exception if this line
                                // is not called within this method of the
                                // child?
        // now do something extra that only Minion knows how to do
    }
}
```

- how do you design the Enemy class so that it has a method which does something, but requires every child to override it?
- how do you force the child (who had to override the method) to also call the parent's method?

this is almost like Android's  `Activity` class that has the onCreate, onStart, onResume...etc. methods that are optional, but if you make use of it, it forces you to call super. it can't be abstract because i want some code to be run when the method is called (which is only in the parent class's method). bonus points if u know how they did it this way?

Comment: To force an override function to call its super, add this annotation to the function in super class: `@CallSuper`.  Android Studio will give you the alert just like `onCreate`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Android Sources use a boolean called `mCalled` that is set to true inside of the quasi-abstract method implementation. In your case that would be inside of the original `updatePosition()`.

Then when you want to call `updatePosition()`, call it through this:

```
private void performUpdatePosition() {
    mCalled = false;
    updatePosition();
    if (!mCalled) throw new SuperNotCalledException();
}
```

and `updatePosition()` would look like this

```
protected void updatePosition() {
    mCalled = true;
    updateBounds();
}
```

EDIT:

Now that I think about it, the way android does it is a little round about. Because all calls to `updatePosition()` are going through `performUpdatePosition()`, you no longer need to have some code inside `updatePosition()` that can be overridden, but shouldn't.

A much better approach is to simply move the required actions to `performUpdatePosition()`:

```
private void performUpdatePosition() {
    updateBounds();
    updatePosition();
}

protected void updatePosition() {
    //Do nothing by default
}
```

This way the callee doesn't have to worry about calling `super.updatePosition`. If the subclass doesn't override that function, then nothing extra will happen, whereas if they do, the override will add on to the previous behavior.

Comment: hmm... okay. i was hoping there'd be a more baked-in solution already in java that i'm just not aware of. but i guess this hack will have to do for now. thanks!!! upvoted (a couple days ago) & accepted

Comment: I have edited the question, giving another (better) method of solving this problem.

Answer (score 5):

maybe instead of you calling the child method, you could define a base method in the class

```
public void updatePosition()
{
    //do what you need to do before the child does it's stuff
    onUpdatePosition();
    //do what you need to do after the child does it's stuff
}

protected abstract void onUpdatePosition();
```

that way, as you call updatePosition(), the child has to have it's own onUpdatePosition() and you know that the stuff the parent does happens everytime

Answer (score -1):

> how do you design the Enemy class so that it has a method which does
>   something, but requires every child to override it?

To do this your parent class methods need to be defined as abstract method, that is only way that child class knows that method defined in parent class needed to be defined in child class.

> how do you force the child (who had to override the method) to also
>   call the parent's method?

Overriding a method is done if parent class is abstract class.

Comment: the OP wants to be able to force execution of some common code during `updatePosition()` and still allow it to be overridden by throwing an exception if it doesn't hit the common code.

Answer (score -3):

how about

```
public abstract class Enemy extends GameObject{
    public abstract void updatePositionCommon(){ 
        //code common to all

        updatePosition();
    }
    public abstract void updatePosition(){ 
        //override this method in children
    }

}
```

Comment: abstract methods can't have bodies.